# Transfer user input into csv file in rshiny

Tags: r, csv, shiny

In SHINY, how can we transfer a user input from some text and numeric boxes into a CSV file ?

The process flow will be that:

```
- First the users input the information into those text boxes.
- Then the users press a Run button
- Upon pressing the button, a CSV file will be generated containing the information from those text boxes
```

Comment: Fetch all the input fields and construct the csv?

Comment: Yes @RomanLuštrik but I'm not sure how to go about with that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the data as a dataframe in a reactive expression, and use a downloadbutton and downloadhandler to download the data.

server.R

```
library(shiny)

shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  dataReactive <- reactive({
data.frame(text = c(input$text1, input$text2, input$text3))

  })

  output$exampleTable <- DT::renderDataTable({
    dataReactive()
  })

  output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() { 
      paste("dataset-", Sys.Date(), ".csv", sep="")
    },
    content = function(file) {
      write.csv(dataReactive(), file)

    })


})
```

ui.R:

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      textInput("text1","Text 1:",value="example text 1"),
      textInput("text2","Text 2:",value="example text 2"),
      textInput("text3","Text 3:",value="example text 3"),
      downloadButton('downloadData', 'Download data')

    ),
    mainPanel(
                DT::dataTableOutput("exampleTable")
    )
  )
))
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you, Florian! It was of great help and works perfectly. Is there another version without the download button in which the user does not get the CSV file back. I want to know as I am transferring it into a metafile

Comment: Glad I could help. Instead of a downloadbutton and downloadhandler, you could also use an actionbutton and an observeEvent, and use write.csv to store the file on your server.

Comment: Something like this?
UI ---- actionButton('action', 'Data') ||
SERVER ----- output$action <- observeEvent(
    filename = function() { 
      paste("dataset-", Sys.Date(), ".csv", sep="")
    }
    content = function(file) {
      write.csv(dataReactive(), file)
    })

Comment: server part should look like this: output$action <- observeEvent( input$action,{
write.csv(dataReactive(),"filenamehere.csv"  ) } )